# Microsoft Graph delegated permission and user consent

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a application in C# with a tenant id, secret, client id in delegated mode for Microsoft Graph Calendar calling.

I have see that several Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient use the following scope:

```
string MS_SCOPE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

TokenCredential TokenCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(TenantID, ClientID, ClientSecret);

GraphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(TokenCredential, SCOPES);
```

But I need with my C# application in delegated mode, have the logged user consent to user.read and calendars.readwrite.shared rights. Consequently, shoudl I create the GraphServiceClient with "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" as a scope OR "User.Read"+"Calendars.ReadWriteShared"

Maybe both "User.Read"+"Calendars.ReadWriteShared"+"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" ?
Thank you very much

I expect a explanation of the behavior and a code part if possible

Comment: Are you positive that you have to use the /.default scope? There is a really good article on Dev.to, which explains it's usage. Please do read it and rephrase your question so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve and help you :)

 : https://dev.to/425show/just-what-is-the-default-scope-in-the-microsoft-identity-platform-azure-ad-2o4d#:~:text=When%20must%20I%20use%20the%20/.default%20scope%3F

Comment: `/.default` for application mode but not delegate mode. If you'd integrated sign in module into your application, you need to use delegate mode, then the scope should be "User.Read"+"Calendars.ReadWriteShared"

Comment: @TinyWang thank you very much, consequently If I want to create a GraphServiceClient with delegated mode, I don't need to add /.default scope right ? Because I got a error yesterday.

Comment: delegated mode doesn't require /.default scope, don't add this scope for delegate mode, or you will get error.

Comment: thank again @TinyWang BTW do you have a code part example for doing this plz ? by providing a tenant id, client id, secret and these scope for GraphServiceClient ?

Comment: pls choose the suitable sample to follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

Comment: yes but for the C#, what I should select n your opinion ? In terme of case ? (I will use ASP.NET Core) Because there is sing in users, OpenID connect, Authorization code, On-Beharlf-Of ... But I don't know the good use case to do that. Our case is to use a delegate mode with an application registered in Azure, and after use  "User.Read" + "Calendar.ReadWriteShare" user's consent, but the API calling the GraphServiceClient, at the beginning have the secret, clientid and tenantid. Should I re instanciate the GraphServiceClient with the access_token of the user after user's consent ? I'm lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the access token using the secret, ClientID and tenanted you can use Get access on behalf of a user method :

[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mehtab Siddique sorry but it a little bit changed, I need to request a access token now with a certificat and not a client secret ... did you know how to do that in C# plz ?